# How to fire jQuery script in PHP if statement

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to get a jQuery script to update the content of an HTML paragraph tag variously according to whether or not a PHP `if` statement, which checks for data in a database, evaluates to true or not:

```
if ($num_rows > 0) { ?> // If results are returned from database...

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('p.message').text('Some data');   // ... p should read 'Some data'
   });
 </script>

<?php else {            // otherwise
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('p.message').text('No data');    // ...p should read 'No data'
   });
 </script>
}
```

The contents of  are intended to change dynamically without the need for a page refresh, but do not do so. Only after the page has been refreshed is the new value shown.

Any ideas as always much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot execute jQuery on server.

Comment: PHP executes on the server. The generate html/script will contain **ONLY** the results of your `if()` at the time the php code is executed. if the variable changes later, the JS code for the OTHER condition will physically not be present in your page.

Comment: php is server-side, javascript is client-side. php code can't be ran from the client other than by using ajax.

Comment: Thanks guys. Any ideas on how to achieve what I want? To get different content into that p tag according to the database contents?

Comment: What u need to show ? u need to get data from server without refreshing ?

Answer (score 3):

Use AJAX to get the content from PHP. You can have the `success` populate the data into your HTML.

Comment: Thanks Biotox and the other respondents. I did it with AJAX and `success` and it's working fine. Not a good question - I realised after asking that PHP and jQuery cannot communicate - it was a long day!

Answer (score 2):

What You are trying to do can be achived through Ajax. Belwo Is a simple Example

**Jquery**

```
 setInterval(function(){UpdateMessage()},10000) // Will Eecute after 10 Seconds

 function UpdateMessage()
 {
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"Script.php",
  success: function(data)
               {
                $(".message").text(data);
               }
       });//END OF Second AJAX
   }
```

**HTML**

```
   <p class='message'></p>
```

**Script.php**

```
 if ($num_rows > 0)
 echo "SOME DATA";
 else
 echo "No Record";
```

above code will refresh Your Data every after 10 Seconds Without Refresh

Answer (score 1):

did you try include `jquery` into that php file? like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```